# How to set user permissions on ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions, acl

I have a problem. I would like to set permissions on my server. I have following directories structure:

- `/var/www/html/project_1`
- `/var/www/html/project_2`
- `/var/www/html/project_3`

I have also users:

- `user_1`
- `user_2`
- `user_3`

My goal is to give users permissions to specified directories, for example "user_1" should only have permissions only to "project_1" and "project_2".

I would like to have a simple way to add and remove users permissions to directories. How can I do this?

Thanks for help.
BR

Comment: What have you looked into so far for managing this, if anything?

Comment: Hi There! What are you exactly trying to achieve with this? Is this for those users to login via FTP and control or some sort of application or  anything else... I'm lost actually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this is "simple" enough for you, but it can be done using tools already included in the system.

---

This can be easily accomplished using the `chmod` and `chown` commands. With `chown` you can set the ownership of files and directories and with `chmod` you can set permissions.

As you may want multiple users to access a single directory, you'd have to create a user group for it and add users to it:

```
groupadd g_project_1
useradd -G g_project_1 user_1
#Repeat useradd for every user who is to access project_1
```

Now you set the ownership group of `project_1` to `g_project_1` (I don't know whether it's necessary, but you may want to keep `www-data` as the ownership user of the directory) so you'd execute this command:

```
chgrp g_project_1 project_1
```

Now you need to set the directory permissions to 0770 (rwx***** for the user, rwx for the group and no access for others):

```
chmod 0770 project_1
```

To ensure files and directories inside receive the same ownership at creation, also execute the following command:

```
chmod g+s project_1
```

Do this analogously for other project directories and users. **Please try it on one dummy project first**, it may well be that I made a mistake...

***** Executable permission on a directory controls whether someone can enter it (`cd`), whereas reading permission controls seeing its contents (`ls`)

Comment: I will try your solutions in the evening. I tried almost like you but chown was www-data:group. I hope it works. Later i try and write. Thanks

Comment: Ok, but in chown command who should be owner and which group should be set?

Comment: The syntax is `chown group:user file`. So as I wrote set the project group as owner group and www-data as the owning user. With the edit, it is a bit more clear, I'd say.

Comment: User owner is "www-data", group owner is "g_project_1", chmod is 770, user "user_1" is in "g_project_1" group, but when I try to create file from the user (via ssh, using touch command), file owner and group is "user_1".

Comment: That's normal. A file belongs to it's creator upon creation. Have a look at [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115631/getting-new-files-to-inherit-group-permissions-on-linux), if you want a way around it.

Comment: I tried, but still created file is owner and group from this user name. My goal is to make permissions for team developers to work with the same project. Maybe it should be done in the other way?

Comment: OK, thanks for help. I had to execute "chmod g+s dir" and everything works very well. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll add it to the answer.